# Google-beta seems to be using non-existent project with google_firebase_project. What should I do?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

#### Objective

I am trying to fix a Firebase deployment managed in Terraform. My module looks something like this...

```
data "google_client_config" "default_project" {
    provider = google-beta
}
data "google_project" "project" {
    provider = google-beta
    project_id = var.gcp_project
}
 
resource "google_firebase_project" "default" {
    provider = google-beta
    project  = var.gcp_project
}

# enable billing API
resource "google_project_service" "cloud_billing" {
    provider = google-beta
    project = google_firebase_project.default.id
    service = "cloudbilling.googleapis.com"
}

# enable firebase
resource "google_project_service" "firebase" {
    provider = google-beta
    project = google_firebase_project.default.id
    service = "firebase.googleapis.com"
}

# enable access context manage api

resource "google_project_service" "access_context" {
    provider = google-beta
    project = google_firebase_project.default.id
    service = "accesscontextmanager.googleapis.com"
}
resource "google_firebase_web_app" "app" {
    provider = google-beta
    project = data.google_project.project.project_id
    display_name = "firestore-controller-${google_firebase_project.default.display_name}"

    depends_on = [
        google_firebase_project.default,
        google_project_service.firebase,
        google_project_service.access_context,
        google_project_service.cloud_billing
    ]
}

data "google_firebase_web_app_config" "app" {
    provider   = google-beta
    web_app_id = google_firebase_web_app.app.app_id
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage" {
    provider = google-beta
    name     = "firestore-controller-${google_firebase_project.default.display_name}"
    location = "US"
}

locals {
  
    firebase_config = jsonencode({
        appId              = google_firebase_web_app.app.app_id
        apiKey             = data.google_firebase_web_app_config.app.api_key
        authDomain         = data.google_firebase_web_app_config.app.auth_domain
        databaseURL        = lookup(data.google_firebase_web_app_config.app, "database_url", "")
        storageBucket      = lookup(data.google_firebase_web_app_config.app, "storage_bucket", "")
        messagingSenderId  = lookup(data.google_firebase_web_app_config.app, "message_sender_id", "")
        measurementId      = lookup(data.google_firebase_web_app_config.app, "measurement_id", "")
    })

}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "firebase_config" {
    provider = google-beta
    bucket = google_storage_bucket.storage.name
    name = "firebase-config.json"

    content = local.firebase_config
}
```

#### Issue

Unfortunately, this fails at `google_firebase_project.default` with the following message:

```
{
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "consumer": "projects/764086051850",
│       "service": "firebase.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
│   }
```

This is strange because a project with that number does not exist (unless it's some kind of root project that I'm having trouble finding). If this is the the project number for some child of the project I am providing to  `google_firebase_project.default` that is also strange; `var.gcp_project_name` certainly has this service enabled.

#### What I've tried thusfar

- Removing tfstate.
- Refactoring back and forth from legacy modules.

I have double-checked and confirmed that the `google-beta` provider does indeed recognize the correct project in its configuration when using `data.google_project` without specifying a `project_id`.

Where is this mysterious `projects/764086051850` coming from?

[cross-post](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/google-beta-seems-to-be-using-non-existent-project-with-google-firebase-project-what-should-i-do/44066)

Comment: `764086051850` is the Google-owned Project that backs `gcloud` and is used by `gcloud` with [`gcloud auth application-default`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default) credentials.

Comment: I don't know (!) but I suspect a solution for you would be to create a Service Account that can be used by your Terraform script.

Comment: One (!) issue with `gcloud`'s use of Application Default Credentials is that you're reliant on the services that Google chooses to enable in its Project. Evidently, Firebase isn't enabled.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks! Other modules seemed to work better with ADC, so I was trying to avoid using a Service Account. But, I guess I can just mix match providers by modules.

Answer (score 4):

You can still accomplish this using Application Default Credentials instead of a service account.

Include the following in the `provider` blocks:

```
        # google-beta
provider "google" {
  project               = var.project_id
  billing_project       = var.project_id
  user_project_override = true
}
```

All requests sent from this provider will leverage `billing_project` as the quota project and `user_project_override` controls requests to GCP APIs for the purpose of preconditions, quota, and billing.

### References

- [`billing_project`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#billing_project)
- [`user_project_override`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#user_project_override)